# Counting instances in a table in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to make a report in Power Bi and failing badly.  I have a db containing test results.  The db has three tables, tests, testresults and statuses.  They look something like this:

| test_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | testb |

| status_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pass |
| 2 | fail |
| 3 | skip |

| result_id | name_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

I am trying to create a report in Power Bi that will have a table that contains a list of tests and how many times each test failed.  I have tried adding a measure column to the tests table but I always seem to end up with a column that  adds up the status_id.  So if a test passes once and fails  twice, ill  get a count of 5.  How would I write a measure that looks through the  results table  and  counts the number of time each test fails?

I hoping to get something that looks like:

| test | failed count |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | 2 |
| testb | 1 |
| testc | 6 |

Comment: Do your tables have relationships set up? What measure(s) are you using?

Comment: Yes they do.  This is my first  attempt at a measure so none yet.

Comment: Can you show what your desired result would be?

Comment: Edited my question to show what i am looking for for  a result.  I  hope  to eventually filter by time ie "show me all the failures for this month" but for now i'd like to at least see a count of failures per test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a simple filter condition like this:

```
failed count = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Results ), Statuses[name] = "fail" )
```

Comment: THANK YOU!   that is exactly what i needed.  i have been  banging my head  on  this for days.